# Java Appium Test failed to run on AWS Device Farm

Tags: java, android, maven, amazon-web-services

I have Appium script in Java language which recoreded by Appium Insecptor.

My script is going to do only 5 steps:

1. Click username field
2. Input username
3. Click password field
4. Inout password
5. Click login button

I would like to run my script on AWS Device Farm.

I did follow the [document](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html) of AWS Device Farm to modify my `pom.xml` file, packaged it by using Maven package `mvn clean package -Dskiptests=true` and finally uploaded the `zip-with-dependencies.zip` to AWS Device Farm.

But my test failed to run.
Here are the screenshots of the result

[image: Screenshot of my result 1]
[image: Screenshot of my result 2]

I don't know where I did mistake to make AWS failed to run my script.

Here is what I recorded,

```
package com.hostname.myapp;

import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;


public class AppiumTest {

    private static AppiumDriver<AndroidElement> wd;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws MalformedURLException {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/X/X.apk");
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.hostname.myapp");
        wd = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
        if (wd != null) {
            wd.quit();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws IOException {
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("android.widget.EditText[1]")).click();
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys("username");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("android.widget.EditText[2]")).click();
        wd.findElement(By.name("Android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys("password");
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("android.widget.Button[1]")).click();
        wd.close();
    }
```

Comment: Check if same script works fine on a physical device or not. Try using `wd = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);` and verify if element locators and their values are correct.

Answer (score 3):

I work for the AWS Device Farm team.

Thank you for the detailed information. This helps.

**Solution**

1. **Desired Capabilities**: Device farm ignores the desired capabilities that you have used. Since you upload the app separately in device farm and choose the device while scheduling a run the device type, name and other capabilities that you use in your code will not be honored and any code that depends on it most likely will not work. 
   Creating an empty desired capability object and passing that to the AndroidDriver constructor would be the ideal way to approach this.
2. **Android Driver**: The code that you used

   `wd = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`

   should be

   `wd = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);`
3. **Video**:  We have video recording capability for both iOS and Android. When a test fails it helps immensely if there is a video of that run. You can check this under the "Files" tab. It could be the case that a pop appeared on the device or some other unexpected event while running the test. The video should give you more insight in this case.

I would suggest trying these 3 changes. Let me know if you are still unable to proceed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Nikof, I have several questions cause I'm very new to AWS & Appium
1. Should I leave Desired Capabilities blank before I upload? I found nothing different with or without them.
2. After I change the IP into 127.0.0.1, there is a different error: 
"An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.", [detail here](http://pastebin.com/hVnnb6t3)  but the parameter is recorded by Appium Inspector. I think it should be correct.
3. Yes, I know there is video record.

Comment: I need your help, @Nikof =(

Comment: Hi Kevin,
Sorry for the delay.
1. Yes. Recommended to leave it blank.
2. Can you share the run url with me as I can use it to look up more details to zero down on the cause of the issue.

Comment: Thank Nikof, https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/home?region=us-west-2#/projects/1a17ba25-ac24-4648-8bcd-ae680f7fbe88

Comment: Hi @NikofTime, I did try the Android Sample code from [AWS Github](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android) and posted a new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39381490)

Comment: Thank you Kevin for sharing the link. Can you point to the exact run and device where you get the error so basically click on device level in the console and on the exact test which gives you the error and then share the link with me? Makes my job a lot easier.