# 'An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters' on Appium while uploading to AWS Device Farm

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium

I am using a sample app from AWS Github

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-device-farm-sample-app-for-android

I have Appium script recorded by Appium Inspector.

```
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import java.net.URL;

public class AppiumTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "HTC");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/Kelvin/Dropbox/app-debug.apk");
        wd = new AppiumDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        wd.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        //Click hamburger menu
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.ImageButton[1]")).click();
        //Go to 'Login Page'
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[8]")).click();
        //Input username: admin
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[1]")).sendKeys("admin");
        //Input password: password
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.EditText[2]")).sendKeys("password");
        //Click login
        wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.RelativeLayout[1]/android.widget.Button[1]")).click();

        wd.close();
    }
}
```

After I package it with MAVEN and upload to AWS Device Farm
2 error messages returned:

1. Argument was an invalid selector
2. An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.

I'm not sure how doesn't script from Appium Inspector works on AWS Device Farm, but I can “Replay” inside Appium Inspector.

I would like to where do my search parameters go wrong. Thank you.

Here's a zoom in look of it

> wd.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.LinearLayout[1 ]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.widget.LinearLayout[1]/android.view.View[1]/android.widget.ImageButton[1]")).click();

Comment: Hi @NikofTime, I hope you can answer my question

Comment: I don't have any experience with AWS but first of all I would first check if the app actually opens up because the path "/Users/Kelvin/Dropbox/app-debug.apk" is probably not relevant when launching the test in the cloud

Comment: Yes, my app did launch in AWS. The main problem is about my script. I am using XPath, do you have any idea about using Appium Inspector?

Comment: Is there a strong reason on why you are using xpath and not and not by id? Is the app you are uploading a hybrid app?

Comment: Thank @NikofTime again. Actually I don't know much about Appium, I am trying to do 'Blackbox testing'. I'm using Xpath because I would like to simply my work: I was told Appium Inspector can record action like click, scoll, sendKey without understanding code. Thus I use it to do so, and the output result is Xpath.

Comment: Do you mean I shall not use Xpath for Appium testing? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: XPath is known to be not reliable at times as it can change from device to device. Can you see any other unique identifier to locate the element? Have you tried using Fluent wait or increasing the implicit wait times to see if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you are working AWS Device Farm you do not need to set DesiredCapabilities and device farme take care of it. 
   So from your above code Remove the code mentioned below -

   DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
   capabilities.setCapability("appium-version", "1.0");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
   capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "5.0.2");
   capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "HTC");
   capabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/Kelvin/Dropbox/app-debug.apk");

2.AWS Device farm uses Appium Version 1.4.10 so make sure locally also you use same version so that after uploading it will not give any errors.

Comment: Thank @Anuja. I did try to remove DesiredCapabilities but the result is same. I have Appium GUI 1.5.3(Ara) installed on my Mac. Should I downgrade it?

Comment: I feel downgrading it might work. If you use same version of appium then there are more chances to make it work